# put a limit on a password's introduction in python

Tags: python

My question is: how can I put a limit on a wrong password introduction and make it as a function?

I'm trying to make it with **in range**

```
if password == (password1):
    print('Please wait')
    print('Correct, logging in.')
    exit

for password in range(5):
    if password != (password1):
        print('Please wait')
        print('Incorrected, closing program.')

        exit
```

but it repeats as a loop 5 times.

Comment: just `break` if password is correct! and don't use `password` as your range variable, as it is an integer!!

Comment: Do you **assign** to `password`? Do you call `input()`? What is `exit`? This surely is not your entire program. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are having two question close-votes saying "unclear what you are asking". Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15198806) and clarify your requirement else it will be closed by the community.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something on the lines of this? I'm not really sure! This program will allow you to enter the wrong password 5 times before quitting.

```
password1 = "hello"


i=0
while i<=4:
    password = raw_input("Enter password: ")
    if password1 == password:
        print "Welcome"
        break
    else:
        print "Try Again. %d tries left" %(4-i)
        i+=1
else:
    print "oops, you ran out of tries"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for .. in range loop, you can ask the user to re-enter at the beginning of the loop,

```
from getpass import getpass
import random
import sys
import time

def validate_user_password(password, attempts=5):
    for attempts_remaining in reversed(range(attempts)):
        prompt='Please enter the password ({} attempts remaining): '.format(attempts_remaining + 1)
        entry = getpass(prompt=prompt)

        print('Please wait...')

        # Wait random amount between 0.5s and 1s
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1))

        if entry == password:
            print('Correct, logging in.')
            return True
        else:
            print('Incorrect password.')
    # All attempts failed
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    password = 'chewbacca'

    if validate_user_password(password):
        print('Admin powers unlocked.  Here are the rocket launch codes: 1-2-3-4-5')
    else:
        print('Closing program.')
        sys.exit(-1)
```

Note: the getpass built-in library hides the password entry, so that someone looking over your shoulder can't see what you've typed in.  The random sleep/wait is an example of one security measure that would help in preventing users from using timing attacks (not that it is likely to help in this case).